# accept attribute doesn't accept certain mime types

Tags: html, mime-types

I'm using the accept attribute on a file input field but certain MIME types don't work. Most MS Office formats work fine like `xls`, `xlsx`, `doc`, `docx`, etc but Visio (`vsd`) and Publisher (`pub`) files do not and neither to rich text (`rtf`).

I've tried the following MIME types:

```
application/vsd
application/vnd.visio
application/ms-visio
application/x-visio
application/visio
application/visio.drawing
application/x-vsd
application/x-mspublisher
text/richtext
application/rtf
application/x-rtf
```

Are only certain types valid for `accept`? I've tested in both Chrome and IE11.

Comment: It is working as it should be -https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/7/

Comment: @AmbrishPathak OK, it worked when not using mime types and just adding the extensions directly as in your fiddle. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Mac Chrome: when I only wanted the user to be able to upload Excel files, I tried each the following MIME types:

- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- application/excel
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/x-excel
- application/x-msexcel

However, when using one of these, the browser would let me choose: Excel, Word, PowerPoint and PDF files (but not image files, so it was in fact trying to validate).

Specifying the extension instead of the MIME type did work:

```html
<input accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```